# What Mega Bloks set is this? Purple-ish, roughly egg-shaped vehicle

Tags: set-identification, clone-brands

[image: I need the theme and set name please]

I need the theme and set name please.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is part of  megaconstrux set # 97110

[Covenant Spectre Ambush](https://www.megaconstrux.com/en-us/halo/sets/covenant-spectre-ambush-97110)

[image]

from the Halo theme

Comment: thanks man some how when i looked at a vid of all sets in halo theme it never showed this one

Comment: @LightEnder If the answer has helped you please take the time to accept it by clicking on the checkmark sign on the left side.